# Handling Errors with intent parameters and Dynamic options with Siri

Tags: swift, siri, sirishortcuts

- I've an intent parameter set as `dynamic` from the intent definition.
- Let's say that the server where I get information for this option is currently down.

It is not clear how to present to users the fact that the options at the moment cannot be retrieved. The completion field where we should return the options also accepts an `Error`. 
I've filled it with a subclass of `Error` and I've also implemented the `LocalizedError` protocol for this class... but when I encounter the error from the shortcut App, Apple is just presenting a pop up message that returns a terrible message not localized (but that includes the right Error name).

Here is the code that I'm using...

```
func provideCarModelOptions(for intent: CarIntent, with completion: @escaping ([String]?, Error?) -> Void) {

    if(somethingGoesWrongWithServers()){
        completion([],CarError.ServerDown)
    }else{
        completion(ReturnListOfModels(), nil)
    }
}
```

And this is how I've implementend the `CarError` enum

```
public enum CarError:Error{
    case serverDown
    case generic
}

extension CarError : LocalizedError{
    public var errorDescription: String? {
        switch self {

        case .serverDown:
            return "Server is down"

        case .generic:
            return "SomethingGoesWrong"

        }

    }
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong or Apple is not handling the Errors the right way?

Comment: Not quite sure I follow your requirement. But have you tried adding your own custom type to capture a specific event in your execution. That way if your server errors out you can capture it in your type and handle it accordingly.

Comment: Were you able to figure it out? I'm facing the same issue where I need to return a custom error from `provide...Options(for intent: ...)` method and iOS displays only error case name from the error enum, not the localized description.

Comment: will any of you found the solution for this? i am having same issue?

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me to provide localized description:

```
completion(nil, INIntentError.init(_nsError: NSError(domain: "com.Domain.error", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Error Message"])))
```